# Laravel class not found because of Vendor folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently implementing a token based authentication system in my API. This was build by Tappleby and it's installed in the Vendor folder of my Laravel installation. This works great as a filter. However, I need some functions of the package in my controller. I added `use Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthToken;` to the controller and added the necessary lines to `__construct`. That doesn't work though, because I keep getting `Class AuthTokenDriver does not exist`.

Is that because the file is in the Vendor folder? Below you can see the controller, but please not that `Tappleby\AuthToken\Exceptions\NotAuthorizedException` is located in the Vendor folder.

```
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;

use Tappleby\AuthToken\Exceptions\NotAuthorizedException;

class ApiUsersController extends ApiController {

    /**
    * @var Acme\Transformers\UserTransformer
    */

    protected $UserTransformer; 

    /**
    * The event dispatcher instance.
    *
    * @var \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher
    */
    protected $events;

    /**
    * @var \Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenDriver
    */
    protected $driver;

    function __construct(UserTransformer $userTransformer, UserLessonsTransformer $userLessonssTransformer, AuthTokenDriver $driver, Dispatcher $events)
    {

        $this->UserTransformer = $userTransformer;

        $this->UserLessonTransformer = $userLessonTransformer;

        $this->driver = $driver;

        $this->events = $events;

    }

    public function index() 
    {

        $payload = Request::header('X-Auth-Token');

        if(empty($payload)) {

            return $this->respondNotFound('User does not exist.');

        }

        $user = $this->driver->validate($payload);

        return $payload;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Vendor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages) folder is what [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) uses for maintaining your packages for you. So if another server or someone else wanted to check your project out, rather than porting over all those powerful packages Laravel uses and extras, they can download themselves via Composer.

However in this case you will need to look into the documentation for this package and make sure you've followed all the instructions like including the [ServiceProvider](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers) in your `app/config/app.php`also stated on the readme: -

https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token

I'm not quite 100% clear on this particular package but remember to dump your autoloader after : -

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Finally to allow the controller to use it in this class, try this with your other dependencies listed: -

```
use \Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenDriver;
```

Comment: Then I get this: `Target [Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenProviderInterface] is not instantiable.`

Comment: You probably shouldn't call the AuthDriver directly then. It's probably easier and cleaner to give an alias by adding this from the docs into your `app/config/app.php` :-



`'AuthToken' => 'Tappleby\Support\Facades\AuthToken',
'AuthTokenNotAuthorizedException' => 'Tappleby\AuthToken\Exceptions\NotAuthorizedException'`

Comment: Okay, I removed it, but already had the aliases set up from the installation. The concept of aliases is still unclear to me though. How do I use those now?

Comment: It looks like from the docs that you can call AuthToken statically like `AuthToken::create();` or `AuthToken::publicToken();`.

The use of an alias is just to make it cleaner and the ServiceProvider with a 'Facade' make it possible to call non-static classes, statically. There's quite a lot to learn, I'd recommend https://laracasts.com/ which is a brilliant resource.